# Bulk deletes/updates in hibernate: best approach?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know in hibernate (or even in JPA?) bulk delete operations are not cascaded to related entities.

Let's assume you have following entities A, B and C.
B has a ManyToOne relationship with A but this is not inverted (so A does not have a list of B's).
C has a ManyToOne relationship with B but also this is not inverted (so B does not have a list of C's).

Now, if an A gets deleted then I want all B's referencing this A to be deleted and all C's referencing these B's to be deleted as well. Since there is no cascading I need to propagate these deletes myself. So the question is what would be the best approach to go about this:

1. sql (delete from C where b_id IN (select is from B where a_id in (select id from A ...
2. using hibernate: load all C's for A and then delete those entities and then load all B's for A and delete those; finally delete A
3. ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think HQL is the better option

Comment: +1 I would also recommend using JPQL if you're using Hibernate through JPA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hibernate to execute native sql statements. For example you can write something like that:

```
session.createSQLQuery("delete from C where b_id IN (select is from B where a_id in (select id from A ...");
```

and you can check this guide [Hibernate native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)